# Solving $y^2 > x^2$ why doesn't these two ways work?

Tags: inequality

For the inequality
$y^2>x^2$
First way I did it was:
$$y>x \quad \textbf{or} \quad y<-x.$$

Another way is by considering $x^2 < y^2$ (so just looking at it from another way)
solution is:
$$-y<x<y \iff -y < x \quad \textbf{and}\quad x < y.$$

So for the first case, on a cartesian plane I would highlight (on the $x-y$ plane) every single set of $(x,y)$ above the line $y=x$ and below the line $y=-x$, so the only "unshaded" bit is a infinitely long triangle piece on the right side of the plane.

For the second case, I would only highlight the "top triangle" on the plane.
Both are wrong because it seems we highlight the "top" triangle and the "bottom" triangle as the solution..

(The triangles I'm referring to are the four pieces on the plane you'd visually see once you put in the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$.)

Comment: $y>-x$ does not imply $y^2>x^2$. Consider $x=2,y=1$.

Comment: Sorry, my initial query should've written $y<-x$, so the rest of the question is unchanged

Comment: Still, $y>x$ does not imply $y^2>x^2$. Consider $x=-2,y=1$.

Comment: But doesn't $y^2 > x^2$ imply $y>x$, so it's the other way around

Comment: Why does $y^2>x^2$ imply $y>x$? Consider $x=1,y=-2$.

Comment: The correct solution is factoring to $(y-x)(y+x)>0$, so $y-x$ and $y+x$ are both positive or both negative.

Comment: Ah I see. And for that implication, I always thought that if $x^2 > a$ then $x >  a$ or $x < -a$?

Comment: @Natash1 You're thinking of $|x|>a$ meaning $x>a$ or $x < -a.$ In this case we have $|y| > |x|$ which indeed means $y>|x|$ or $y < -|x|.$ Now draw the graph of $|x|$ and $-|x|$ and shade the appropriate regions and you'll see you get to the same answer.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry I meant the square root of $a$. And I see now, so this is how it would've been done (using method 2):  
$x^2 < y^2 \iff -|y|<x<|y| \iff |y|>-x$ and $|y| > x \iff (y > -x$ or $y < x)$ and $(y>x$ or $y<-x)$?